# sparql don't return results even page exist

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

When running a SPARQL [http://dbpedia.org/sparql] to find pages related to some word (as label or redirect using UNION to support each one, but no results are displayed, even the related page exist .

There is something wrong with my query or using UNION in a wrong way?

```sql
SELECT ?resource ?name ?wikipage ?comment 
WHERE { 
{ ?resource rdfs:label 'Pencil lead'@en . }
UNION 
{ ?redirect rdfs:label 'Pencil lead'@en ; dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects ?resource . }
?resource dbpprop:label ?name ; foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikipage ; rdfs:comment ?comment . 
FILTER (langMatches(lang(?comment ),'en')) . }
```

But separatly, they works and gives same results for http://dbpedia.org/page/Pencil:

```sql
SELECT ?resource ?name ?wikipage ?comment 
WHERE { 
?redirect rdfs:label ?name ; dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects ?resource . FILTER (?name = 'Pencil lead'@en) . 
?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikipage . 
?resource rdfs:comment ?comment . FILTER (langMatches(lang(?comment ),'en')) . 
}  

SELECT ?resource ?name ?wikipage ?comment 
WHERE { 
?resource rdfs:label ?name . FILTER (?name = 'Pencil'@en) . 
?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikipage . 
?resource rdfs:comment ?comment . FILTER (langMatches(lang(?comment ),'en')) . 
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether it's your problem or not, but do note that the resource is not `http://dbpedia.org/page/Pencil`;  that's just a human readable representation.  The resource is `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Pencil`.  If you try to retrieve the latter in a web browser, you get *redirected* to the former, but they're not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your working query uses **rdfs:label**:

```
?resource rdfs:label ?name . FILTER (?name = 'Pencil'@en) .
```

Your broken query uses **dbprop:label**:

```
?resource dbpprop:label ?name ;
          foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikipage ; rdfs:comment ?comment .
```

You should use **rdfs:label** in both.

That said, there's no reason to use **union** here at all.  You can do this with a property path, since **?resource** is either something that has, or is the redirect of something that has, **rdfs:label 'Pencil lead'@en**.

```sql
SELECT ?resource ?name ?wikipage ?comment 
WHERE { 
  ?resource (^dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects)?/rdfs:label 'Pencil lead'@en ;
            rdfs:label ?name ;
            foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikipage ;
            rdfs:comment ?comment . 
  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?comment ),'en')) .
}
```

Comment: Thank you,

Yes, notice the difference between page and result. Something I got lost. :)